# Copy last array object to be added to same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I hope this is quite simple. I'm trying to add the last object in a array to the array again.

Like this:

```
arr = [1, 2]

result = [1, 2, 2]
```

Just with this code instead:

```
    $scope.template = {
        ressource: {
            level: [{
                gain: [],
                cost: []
            }]
        }
    };

    $scope.addLevel = function() {
        var last = $scope.template.ressource.level[$scope.template.ressource.level.length - 1];
        $scope.template.ressource.level.push(last);
    };
```

However I'm getting this error:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: level in template.ressource.level, Duplicate key: object:51, Duplicate value: {"gain":[],"cost":[]}

---

**EDIT**

So i've tried the `track by` but I don't seem to be getting anything new so here is the `HTML` part of my code where I use the `gain` and `cost` values:

```
            <div ng-show="template.type === 'building'" class="vertical-spacing">
            <label>Ressource gain per level</label>

            <ul class="list-group">
                <li ng-repeat="level in template.ressource.level track by $id(level)" 
                    class="list-group-item" 
                    ng-hide="template.ressource.level.indexOf(level) === 0">
                    <span>
                        Level: {{ template.ressource.level.indexOf(level) }}
                    </span>

                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <a href="" ng-click="removeLevel(level)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>

                    <ul>
                        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="gain in level.gain track by $id(gain)">
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Amount</label>
                                    <input type="number" 
                                           class="form-control"
                                           ng-model="gain.amount" 
                                           min="1" 
                                           required>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Ressource</label>
                                    <select required 
                                            ng-model="gain.ressource" 
                                            ng-init="gain.ressource = gain.ressource || ressources.basic[0]"
                                            ng-options="ressource._id as ressource.name | capitalize for ressource in ressources.basic"
                                            class="form-control selectWidth">
                                        <option style="display:none" value="" disabled>select a ressource</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <span class="pull-right">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="removeGain(level, gain)">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <span>
                        <a href="" ng-click="addGain(level)" ng-hide="(level.gain.length + 1) > ressources.basic.length">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add ressource
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <span>
                <a href="" ng-click="addLevel()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add level
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="template.type === 'building'" class="vertical-spacing">
            <label>Ressource cost per level</label>

            <ul class="list-group">
                <li ng-repeat="level in template.ressource.level track by $id(level)" 
                    class="list-group-item" 
                    ng-hide="template.ressource.level.indexOf(level) === 0">
                    <span>
                        Level: {{ template.ressource.level.indexOf(level) }}
                    </span>

                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <a href="" ng-click="removeLevel(level)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>

                    <ul>
                        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="cost in level.cost track by $id(cost)">
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Amount</label>
                                    <input type="number" 
                                           class="form-control"
                                           ng-model="cost.amount" 
                                           min="1" 
                                           required>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Ressource</label>
                                    <select required 
                                            ng-model="cost.ressource" 
                                            ng-init="cost.ressource = cost.ressource || ressources.categories[0]"
                                            ng-options="ressource._id as ressource.name | capitalize for ressource in ressources.categories"
                                            class="form-control selectWidth">
                                        <option style="display:none" value="" disabled>select a ressource</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <span class="pull-right">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="removeCost(level, cost)">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <span>
                        <a href="" ng-click="addCost(level)" ng-hide="(level.cost.length + 1) > ressources.categories.length">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add ressource
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <span>
                <a href="" ng-click="addLevel()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add level
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
```

The error now states:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: level in template.ressource.level track by $id(level), Duplicate key: object:51, Duplicate value: {"gain":[],"cost":[]}

Comment: Your pure JavaScript code and logic is correct, it seems to be an AngularJS problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an angular error. Use `track by` in your ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="n in template.ressource.level track by $index">
```

---

*Reference*

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates

> By default, ngRepeat does not allow duplicate items in arrays. This is because when there are duplicates, it is not possible to maintain a one-to-one mapping between collection items and DOM elements.
>
> If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the track by expression.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get it to work. Just added the `HTML` I'm using, maybe that will shed some light on the matter ^^

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard Try `track by $index`

Comment: hmm if I try with `$index` I get no errors, the function is called as it should. But the page ain't changing to allow the new level which has been added.